# Amazon Scraper Bot - VBA/Selenium - Data Scrape Issue

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm in the process of migrating some VBA code from Internet Explorer to Selenium that scrapes data from Amazon .

The code enters a search term, and scrapes items such as ASIN, Selling Price, # of Reviews, etc from the search results.  I can get all the items except Ratings.

The Ratings can be found in two sections of each products hierarchy, both contained inside a span element.

```
<span aria-label="4.3 out of 5 stars">
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.3 out of 5 stars</span>
```

[Please click for Amazon HTML code hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AEOp.png)

```
Sub AMZ_Scraper    

SearchURL = "https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=BIKE+LED+LIGHTS+REAR+FRONT&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"

'Start Edge and Navigate to URL
Dim Browser As New WebDriver
Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys

Browser.Start "edge"
Browser.Get SearchURL

'Find top element
Dim Elements As Selenium.WebElements
        
Set Elements = Browser.FindElementsByCss(".s-result-item")

For Each Element In Elements
                
      Asin = Element.Attribute("data-asin")

      ProductName = Element.FindElementByClass("a-size-base-plus").Text

      Reviews = Element.FindElementByClass("a-size-base").Text

      Rating1 = Element.FindElementByXPath("//div [@class = 'a-row a-size-small']").FindElementByCss("Span").Attribute("aria-label")
      Rating2 = Element.FindElementByXPath("//div [@class = 'a-row a-size-small']").FindElementByXPath("//span [@class = 'a-icon-alt']").Text

Next

End sub
```

The Rating1 code works but it's extracting the same rating (4.4 out of 5 Stars) for every product.

The Rating2 code does not error out but also not extract any data.

How do I extract the value from the element that holds the rating?

Comment: @jsotola Thanks!  I have edited my post to include a question.

Comment: Try this `FindElementByCss("span[aria-label*='star']").Attribute("aria-label")` for the rating portion.

Comment: @SIM It worked!  Thanks for showing me how to use the FindElementByCss locator.  It finds the word star, and retrieves the text.  Thanks again!